# First movss, then unpcklps with zeroes, not changing the high zeros. Why?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, sse

I am new to x86 and have no experience in it, so this code looks kinda obsolete to me. Is there any purpose in doing this?

The instructions are:

rcx+000003F8 = 32bit float

xmm0         = 0 (all 128bits)

```
movss xmm4,[rcx+000003F8]
unpcklps xmm4,xmm0
```

Wouldnt "unpcklps xmm4,xmm0" be obsolete, beacuse it would not change anything in xmm4?

Comment: because all 128 bits in xmm0 are set to 0

Comment: I know. Thats why xmm4 stays the same after unpcklps. I was asking why would you do that, since it would not change the register at all in this case. This instruction seems obsolete because of that

Comment: Re "xmm4 stays the same after unpcklps". Agreed, if one assumes your code snippet uses Intel syntax (as opposed to AT&T syntax), which I notice belatedly seems to be the case based on the `movss` which has the memory source on the right. That is still different from "all 128 bits in xmm0 are set to 0". So yes, `unpcklps xmm4,xmm0` appears to be redundant here. It could be a bug and something else was intended, such as `unpcklps xmm4, xmm4`.

Comment: Are you sure XMM0 is always all-zero on all code paths leading to this?  Is the asm compiler-generated?  If so, did the compiler maybe not know that XMM0 was always zero?  Or was it compiled from intrinsics by MSVC or something that won't optimize intrinsics?  (Maybe from source that used a named variable that happened to be initialized to zero.  Or maybe just a bad / naive implementation of `_mm_setr_ps(x, 0, 0, 0)` by some old compiler.)

Comment: i think so. i was debugging the application, which is a 64 bit game (pretty new also) and the value is always 0.  i cant tell you how it was compiled, but it i can guarantee, that

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility of this code being reached by jump, from somewhere that xmm0 is not zero?

Answer (score 5):

This is probably braindead code-gen from MSVC 19.20 or earlier, which doesn't know `_mm_setr_ps(x, 0,0,0)` is the same as `_mm_set_ss(x)`.

```
#include <immintrin.h>

__m128 foo(float *xptr){
    return _mm_set_ss(*xptr);  // load and zero-extend a float into a vector
}

__m128 bar(float *xptr){
    return _mm_setr_ps(*xptr, 0,0,0);  // same, but the compiler has to notice
             // that the explicit zeros can be produced for free by MOVSS
}
```

GCC and Clang, and MSVC 19.21 and later, compile both to the expected `movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rcx]` (or `[rdi]` for x86-64 System V calling convention).

But as we can see [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYM9DgDJ4GmADl3ACNMYhAAJg1SAAdUBUJbBmc3Dz04hJsBX38gllDwqItMKyyGIQImYgIU908uYtKkiqqCHMCQsMjohUrq2rSG3tb2vILugEoLVFdiZHYOAFIIgGY/ZDcsAGpFlcc8FhY/AmI/ADoEXexFjQBBG9vTFi4IgA4t/lRqWlQmAi2AFSqGInCaLADsACEHltYVtiJgCLMGFtjIdjEoCBiFBAgSDiGCVpDYQB6ElbH5MdBbQzUgBeYVQAFpMKoCA4aR9Kf9jqhOQA3TDWEgPCEAEVFdyeL3ewSq31%2B/zxoIh0LucPhiORqPRmOIxhiOOVZC20TNhOJWzJWwUrEwpC2wVc/wICEwWzQLBidDCWwQTAUWyIWwYqBs8xhGqjcOtrr%2BQbdW1ZMVoeGQhC2DOI8Q9hkd7pi2fQrnm1P4xA%2BCPdwQAnlsALIAeQAakIhKLwRK7pLHmiZZXUCxjAjgHhemEFfHVGCoZHYQikcQUWih5jsRBp7s1fdOz2HtK3gOhyOx%2Bz9fyIpP/pvZ%2Bq4QvtSuMYj9YaNw6zaQNBaO137ncOCmWhOAAVl4TwOC0UhUE4RwbRmOZ3WWFYeFIAhNEAqYAGsQBWECznBABOQiQK4KQADYuFeEDyMkED9E4SRwIw6DOF4BQQGidDIMA0g4FgJBPW9egyAoCAhJ9cJ%2BWQYx%2BS4QjjCiYxVFo0gsH5NNMGbPBMAAd0bGJGE4VCaFoM8OIgYIWOCPwqhrYzeBs5hiBrRtgm0IVuNQz02EERsGFoeyeLUzAnWARwxFoDjuF4LAWEMYBxGC/AEWsPBBWiqDWSFZ0FlQ44ShY1NgmIOznCwFiTgOBypioAxgAUbS9IMoyYpkQQRDEdgpHa%2BQlDUFjdAaAwjBAUxjHMYqOMgKZUBBJJoqZRsIl4VBBWIU4sGmiApksTyknsBgnBcOovCO0ZOnCBoMkSAQBnqWJ4luhgLvyLohhKfaBBafoTsGRovvKPo2j8Do3quixgfuvRhmqV7xi4XaEPmCQgNA5jgpgjgthUyQthYBRpK2OTCLOKItggXBCBIHZVkR3huK0CYpjdKkuh20gcJWCIzi4DQNAiSRJAicjCI0cEuHBV4GI4JjSBYCR%2BdICCoKx9jOLQjCpn4qAYEQFBB2EsJyEoCSRJQYAuG5kKNPmJr9MMiCTLoczKCs4KnLshzSE9ly3I86xvZ8xgCH8wKWKwMKItoKLvbihKkqglL9oyljsuQXLvYK4DguK0qXPKhYoKqhWYtq%2BrGp0h3WpM2ROvEHr%2BEERQVHUYLdBWfQErGsx9DwYJttm%2BaBEWxsVi2JkAHVIonlgkX8XYxTpBh1pW6D1s2zBB4BtK7AgBxoYaHxQbGd7HsyJJD/P574bPvbd6B1or/vsofpB3JLphqG/oe2H37BhGSNZgo0RjLMCysWJYxxq8ciTJaJbGAMgZAWwrZkwplTIgFZkL001jxZmnNcI8z5gLIWIsxYSyljLOWCsQLRBVqtNiFgNaM14jrCAglDaSRNuJTh5skEjUtuRJW6lNL2xak7XgplXaWWsrZFy3tfauXcp5IOg5fKhwCkFJOoVXDhUitFVC8cjCJ1ingVKNhU7BXTpnNq2cir93zjWQulVTilx4OXJgDUxGO29k3YQogG7SD8S3Aa7dIhd1GuNSa/dt5zTKKPceTI56uAXisJeK8whrzWmETe28X4HX3kdK%2Bx8P7g3SE9MoV8bplFvhDfJ31v6pF/p9B%2Bb9alfyfj/DpcMT6f1AQoZG3U0YcHAfQ1i2NVAwLgXjDYCUUHkTOBoRZ6D8CYNpihCYDMtYs0wGzcIHMc7UJALQiBmNGEcS4tsgh3Neb80FsLUW4tJbSxzisDGqtGEsPwTnNeCtiGnI%2BRwLZeCpjrQSHYSQQA), MSVC 19.20.27525 and earlier make this braindead asm, generating the high elements in another register and shuffling them in.

```
foo     PROC                                          ; COMDAT
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rcx]
        ret     0
foo     ENDP


bar     PROC                                          ; COMDAT
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rcx]
        xorps   xmm1, xmm1
        unpcklps xmm0, xmm1
        xorps   xmm2, xmm2
        unpcklps xmm0, xmm2
        ret     0
bar     ENDP
```

It does know it can generate zeros with `xorps` instead of loading a constant, but doesn't even notice that it could reuse the same zeroed vector twice.  It does manage to use "only" two `unpcklps` instructions instead of the three we'd need for the general case of `_mm_setr_ps(a,b,c,d)` with only SSE2 (not SSE4.1 `insertps`).

Even the oldest versions [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/anhYYoM1P) of other compilers, GCC 4.1 and Clang 3.0, optimized `_mm_set_ps` to just a load.  MSVC 19.14 is from Visual Studio 2017; MSVC's code-gen for intrinsics is I think mostly fine now, although it won't optimize intrinsics much if at all, but it has been worse in the recent past.

---

It's possible that some path of execution jumps to this block without running code that zeros XMM0.

Perhaps you can set a conditional breakpoint on the `unpcklps` which will only trigger with non-zero `xmm0`.  If it never trips while you run the program, and you don't see any branches into the basic block containing it, then probably it's just dumb code-gen from MSVC.